# Two Angular2 apps on one page with one in an iframe? Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, iframe, angular, systemjs

I have created an application in Angular2 with a dashboard that shows different modules to click on. If the user clicks on a module then another Angular2 app will be requested via an iframe. All applications share their scripts by a CDN.

After the user clicks now on a module the following error occurs:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined in angular2-polyfills.js

[image]

I'm using Angular2 Beta 8 and Chrome Version 49.0.2623.75 m (64-bit).

Does anyone have an idea why the error occurs?

The following will be loaded in the parent app and also in the child app which will be hosted in an iframe:

[image]

Both apps will be bootstrapped manually. The parent and the child app bootstrap itself. The child app is nested in the parent app.

Does Angular 2 have problems with two bootstrapping calls on one page?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You've provided zero code.  How would anyone have an idea why you're getting an error?

Comment: edited, thanks.. its my first post